# How to fix this error : Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0)

Tags: java, swing

```
int Prid,newQty;
 public void Update()
 {
     String path="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/supermarket";
     String user="root";
     String pass="123456";
     try {
            con=DriverManager.getConnection(path, user, pass);
            ps = con.prepareStatement("update product set ProdQty="+newQty+""+"where ProdID="+Prid);           
            ps.setInt(1, Prid);               
            ps.executeUpdate();                    
            SelectSeller();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
 }
```

I create int to update database table when calculated, but error

this code for calculate

```
private void ProdTBMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                    
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)ProdTB.getModel();
    int Myindex = ProdTB.getSelectedRow();
    Prid = Integer.valueOf(model.getValueAt(Myindex, 0).toString());
    AvailQty = Integer.valueOf(model.getValueAt(Myindex, 2).toString());        
    try {
        newQty = AvailQty - Integer.valueOf(ProdQty.getText());   
    } catch (Exception e) {
        
    }        
    ProdName.setText(model.getValueAt(Myindex, 1).toString());
    Uprice = Double.valueOf(model.getValueAt(Myindex, 3).toString());      
}
```

I need to change variable ProdQty in product table when newQty = AvailQty - Integer.valueOf(ProdQty.getText());

```
private void AddtoBillActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
if(ProdQty.getText().isEmpty()|| ProdName.getText().isEmpty())
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Missing Information..");
    }
else if(AvailQty <= Integer.valueOf(ProdQty.getText()))
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Not Enough In Stock..");
}
else{
    i++;
        ProdTot = Uprice * Double.valueOf(ProdQty.getText());
        GrdTotal = GrdTotal+ProdTot;
    if(i==1)
    {
        Bill.setText(Bill.getText()+"=============== SHOPPING MORE ==================\n"+" NUM     PRODUCT     PRICE     QAUNTITY     SUBTOTAL\n"+"    "+i+"         "+ProdName.getText()+"      "+Uprice+"              "+ProdQty.getText()+"               "+ProdTot+"\n");
    }
    else
    {
        Bill.setText(Bill.getText()+"    "+i+"         "+ProdName.getText()+"      "+Uprice+"              "+ProdQty.getText()+"               "+ProdTot+"\n");
    }
    Grdtotal.setText("Total "+GrdTotal);
    Update();
}
    
}
```

I'm a new for java please help me thanks.

Comment: I strongly recommend that you read up on prepared statements and parameterised SQL in general. Currently you're including both values directly in your SQL (which is a bad idea in terms of SQL Injection attacks; less so for integers, but it's best to parameterize *everything* non-constant) but expecting *one* of them to be a parameter. They should *both* be parameters, specified in the normal way. Searching for tutorials on PreparedStatement should help you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

you specify that Prid is a [bind variable](https://www.databasestar.com/sql-bind-variables/) but you also embed the value in the sql statement text.
instead of embeddimg the value in the statement, you need to specify the placeholder for the bind variable:
`"update product set ProdQty=" + newQty + " where ProdID = ?"`

it is also advisable to do the same for `newQty`. it improves performance of execution of similar statements, and mitigates the risk for [SQL injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) security vulnerability

Comment: Not going to suggest doing the same for the quantity?

Comment: its solve error but i need int Prid and newQty to calculate this :

Comment: private void ProdTBMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                    
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)ProdTB.getModel();
        int Myindex = ProdTB.getSelectedRow();

Comment: Prid = Integer.valueOf(model.getValueAt(Myindex, 0).toString());
        AvailQty = Integer.valueOf(model.getValueAt(Myindex, 2).toString());        
        try {
            newQty = AvailQty - Integer.valueOf(ProdQty.getText());   
        } catch (Exception e) {
            
        }        
        ProdName.setText(model.getValueAt(Myindex, 1).toString());
        Uprice = Double.valueOf(model.getValueAt(Myindex, 3).toString());       
    }

Comment: you are asking a new question in comment. mark this answer and open new question and stop being ungrateful